# bootstrap - why won't my row class expand to fit my fixed-size div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so I have a working example here:  http://www.bootply.com/16k8ngAUxF#

My question is: why can I see div content2 clearly, but not div content1?

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12" id="header-ads">
      <div>
        <div id="content1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="header">

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="content2">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.row {
    background-color: pink;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
#content1 {
  margin: 4px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content2 {
  margin: 4px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure I follow what your issue is. Content 2 has a bright yellow background over the pink row so it's very pronounced. Content1 only has a light blue border over the pink, making it difficult to see... ?

Comment: No.  If you can see my example at http://www.bootply.com/16k8ngAUxF then you will notice that space is not allotted for content1 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming conventions are causing problems `id="header-ads"` this is one of many of classes that are blocked by adblockers. Im currently using adguard see below the css it inserts into the `<head>` of my webpages, you are most likely using some adblocker aswell.

```
#googlead, #gridAdSidebar, #head-ad, #header-ads, #headerAd, #headerAdContainer, #header_ad, #homead, #ka_adRightSkyscraperWide, #leaderAd, #leaderBoardAd, #leaderboard-ad, #leaderboard-advertisement, #leaderboardad, #left-ad, #left_ads, #leftad, #leftads, #logoAd, #logo_ad {
display: none!important;
}
```